# Is there a way in Skype desktop for Windows to select a contact automatically after startup?

Tags: windows-10, skype, automation, contacts

I usually chat with the same contact most of the time via Skype, so when I start skype I always click on her name, so that our chat is already displayed.

Is there a way to select this contact automatically, so I don't have to click on her name every time skype is started?

Comment: It's s skype desktop on windows 10. I downloaded the desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new desktop shortcut, where in the Target field you will enter this command:

```
skype:[GRANDMA]?call
```

Here, [GRANDMA] (uppercase NOT required) is the exact Skype Name (remove the brackets) of the user the shortcut will initiate a call to. If the Skype Name contains the live: prefix, this prefix should be included too.

See detail at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/sk_call-sk_tocall-sk_win10/the-granma-button-how-to-configure-skype-to-auto/1d3bacae-9c73-49e7-8dde-9bfadad0fa5d

Comment: But I don't want a call. We text chat most of the time. I only want the specific user selected in the contacts list automatically, so her text chat is the one opened by default.

Comment: @Tom Try `skype:[GRANDMA]?text` or `skype:[GRANDMA]?chat`